# show date in( MM-DD) format in x-axis using react-vis

Tags: reactjs, react-vis

I am trying to implement react-vis in my project. I need to show data based on date. I am using tickFormat for it but it is showing same date two times in x-axis.I am adding few lines of my code here.

```
       <XYPlot
        width={1140}
        height={440}
        >
        <LineMarkSeries
           lineStyle={{stroke: '#e0e0e0'}}
            markStyle={{stroke: '#6dc6c1'}}
            style={{
                strokeWidth: '2px'
            }}
            strokeStyle="solid"
            data={[
                {
                    x: Date.parse("05/05/2019"),
                    y: 0
                },
                {
                    x: Date.parse("05/12/2019"),
                    y: 12
                },
                {
                    x: Date.parse("05/13/2019"),
                    y: 16
                }
            ]}
         />
          <XAxis
            attr="x"
            attrAxis="y"
            orientation="bottom"
            tickFormat={function tickFormat(d){return 
                           moment(d).format("MMM DD")}}
            tickLabelAngle={0}
         />
        <YAxis />
    </XYPlot>
```

Comment: Maintain the  moment.format(MM-DD) same date format In data array as well.

Comment: I tried it but it's not working.showing this error(Error: <circle> attribute cx: Expected length, "NaN".) I think this format may not supported inside data array.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify `xType` as `ordinal`, it will use your x value as the tick label (eg: like a bar chart). Thus, you don't have to have a redundant conversion of your x values using `Date.parse`.

```
<XYPlot
  width={1140}
  height={440}
  xType='ordinal'
>
    <LineMarkSeries
      lineStyle={{stroke: '#e0e0e0'}}
      markStyle={{stroke: '#6dc6c1'}}
      style={{ strokeWidth: '2px' }}
      strokeStyle="solid"
      data={[
        {
          x: "05/05/2019",
          y: 0
        },
        {
          x: "05/12/2019",
          y: 12
        },
        {
          x: "05/13/2019",
          y: 16
        }
      ]}
    />
    <XAxis />
</XYPlot>
```

Comment: This will produce a graph where all the dates are next to each other regardless of how much time has elapsed between two dates.